# dynamic tab creation problem

Tags: asp.net

i have created tabs dynamically. each tab contains user controls. now itz taking more time to load. i have nearly 18 tbs to load. any possible solution to speed up this.(like threading , delegates etc).

Comment: You should probably elaborate a bit: What are you trying to achieve? What have you done so far (please describe your asp.net page's overall structure)? What is the problem (please quantify the performance degradation you are seeing)?

Comment: i have created tabs dynamically. each tab contains user controls. now itz taking more time to load. i have nearly 18 tbs to load.i hav no tab at first. i hav a page. say as page1. when i cliked in some events , thn redirect it into another page page2. in that page2's pageload, these dyanmic creation hapens. i can't say wch will be first tab . bocz user can reorder the tab

Answer (score 0):

You only need to render the controls in the visible tab.  The invisible tabs do not need to be rendered for obvious reasons.

Comment: i hav no tab at first. i hav a page. say as page1. when i cliked in some events , thn redirect it into another page page2. in that page2's pageload, these dyanmic creation hapens(tabsnames , usercontols, and itz order is from tabel). i can't say wch will be first tab . bocz user can reorder the tab